# I am creating a React website but getting an error in components loading

Tags: css, reactjs, components

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vf6E.jpg

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\bq562ts\Downloads\yt-finance\src\components\Header.jsx: Unexpected token (7:2)
   5 |     <div>
   6 | export const Header = () => {
>  7 |   return (
     |   ^
```

Comment: Please share the file that you are getting error from, as a text and not an image. Also there are 2 different error in the image, need more explanation.

Comment: hello thanks for answering but i solved it now

Comment: good to hear that, so now you can answer your own question so others can use it, or you can delete your question if you want.

Comment: sure i would do it now